# The Multi.Dictionary component has expired can it be replaced with Scripting.Dictionary?

Tags: iis, dll, asp-classic, translation

I was using the MOTO BIT Mdict as my dictionary component, putting all my translations in the Application object as per the below code, and it worked fine, until the component expired 2 days ago for unknown reasons, 12 years later on.

The MOTO Bit website is not replying - so now I seek help if anyone knows how I can reprogram the code below to use with the build in asp scripting.dictionary instead. Is it possible at all?

---

```
Function Write(strID, Comment)

    If ValidNumber(strID) Then
        If (IsObject(Application("Translation_" & StoryCountry)) = False) OR Debugf = True Then

            SET objDic = Server.CreateObject("Multi.Dictionary")
            'Load the translations into the dic object
            set toRs = conn.execute("EXEC dbo.GetTranslationsByCountryID " & StoryCountry)
                If Not toRs.Eof Then
                    tRow = toRs.GetRows()

                        For tx = 0 To UBound(tRow, 2)
                            IF objDic.Exists(tRow(0, tx)) THEN
                            ELSE
                                strTranslationKey = tRow(0, tx)
                                strTranslationText = tRow(1, tx)

                                objDic.Add strTranslationKey, strTranslationText
                            END IF

                        Next
                    SET Application("Translation_" & StoryCountry) = objDic
                End If
            Set toRs = Nothing

        End If
        Write = Application("Translation_" & StoryCountry)(strID)
    Else
    Write = "Invalid"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Old school ASP is not qualified to use ASP.NET tags.

Comment: Seems very similar, you could just try replacing `SET objDic = Server.CreateObject("Multi.Dictionary")` with `SET objDic = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`. Although, the website appears to be up, [this link](https://www.motobit.com/help/asp-dictionary-object/default.htm) is working.

Comment: Yeah, the website is up, but the owner, does not ship the order, or reply email. So I am left with the help of people with more knowledge than me. I tried the solution you suggested, but get a response as:

ERROR
Number -2147467259
Category Application Object
Source 
Description Disallowed Object Use

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Lord Svendson, using Scripting.Dictionary objects at the Application level is not allowed.  When you attempt to `SET Application("Translation_" & StoryCountry) = objDic`, it errors for this reason.  You will need to find a workaround to using Scripting.Dictionary